# traefik + lets-encrypt + CloudFlare = 6103: Invalid format for X-Auth-Key header

Tags: cloudflare, lets-encrypt, traefik

I'm using **traefik 1.4.0-rc3**, and I want to setup **let's encrypt** to get SSL on my traefik reverse proxy.

**The error is**

```
time="2017-10-01T18:02:02+02:00" level=error msg="map[www.site.com:Error presenting token: Cloudflare API Error 
     Error: 6003: Invalid request headers<- 6103: Invalid format for X-Auth-Key header site.com:Error presenting token: Cloudflare API Error 
     Error: 6003: Invalid request headers<- 6103: Invalid format for X-Auth-Key header]" 
time="2017-10-01T18:02:02+02:00" level=error msg="Error getting ACME certificate for domain [site.com www.site.com]: Cannot obtain certificates map[site.com:Error presenting token: Cloudflare API Error 
     Error: 6003: Invalid request headers<- 6103: Invalid format for X-Auth-Key header www.site.com:Error presenting token: Cloudflare API Error 
     Error: 6003: Invalid request headers<- 6103: Invalid format for X-Auth-Key header]+v"
```

I'm using Traefik on Windows, inside a windows container.

My traefik.toml looks like this:

```
traefikLogsFile = "/logs/traefik.log"
debug = true

[file]
directory = "/etc/sites/"
watch = true

[web]
address = ":8080"

defaultEntryPoints = ["http", "https"]
[entryPoints]
  [entryPoints.http]
  address = ":80"
  [entryPoints.https]
  address = ":443"
    [entryPoints.https.tls]

[acme]
email = "my@email.com"
storage = "C:/ssl/lets-encrypt.json"
entryPoint = "https"
dnsProvider = "cloudflare"
acmeLogging = true
caServer = "https://acme-staging.api.letsencrypt.org/directory"
[[acme.domains]]
  main = "site.com"
  sans = ["www.site.com"]
```

I run traefik in a container like this:

```
docker run -d -e CLOUDFLARE_EMAIL=my@email.com -e CLOUDFLARE_API_KEY=v1.0-...abc -p 80:80 -p 8080:8080 -p 443:443 -v... traefik
```

I have verified that I am using the Origin CA Key

**Can you please help?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use the Global API Key instead, as the Origin CA Key is not supported.

Source:
https://github.com/containous/traefik/pull/2558